# Undefined reference to 'HashTable::HashTable()'

Tags: c++, reference

I'm working on a testing program for a lab and I keep getting the error

```
[jereminp@bondi hw3]$ make insert_test
g++  -O3 -g -o insert_test.o -c insert_test.cc
g++ -O3 -g -o insert_test insert_test.o
insert_test.o: In function `main':
/users/ugrad/2018/fall/jereminp/114/hw3/hw3/insert_test.cc:17: undefined reference to `HashTable::HashTable()'
/users/ugrad/2018/fall/jereminp/114/hw3/hw3/insert_test.cc:24: undefined reference to `HashTable::insert(int)'
/users/ugrad/2018/fall/jereminp/114/hw3/hw3/insert_test.cc:32: undefined reference to `HashTable::insert(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [insert_test] Error 1
```

I'm fairly certain I have the logic, but I can't get past this error and I feel like I'm missing something simple. Here's the parts of the code in question.

Makefile

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS =
COPTFLAGS = -O3 -g

insert_test: insert_test.o
    $(CC) $(COPTFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

insert_test.cc

```
#include "HashTable.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class HashTable;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //checks .5 and .9 1x
  int numRuns = 0;
  int numProbes = 0;
  int a=0;
  HashTable h;
```

HashTable.hh

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H


class HashTable
{
  public:
  HashTable();
  /* implement copy constructor, assignment, destructor if needed */
  int hashfnc(int key);
  int insert (int value); 
  /* insert the input value and return the number of probes
   * return -1 if the table is full and insert fails */

  bool find (int value, int& nProbes);  
  /* Search for the input value in table
   * Return true if the search is successful, otherwise false
   * Save # probes in 'nProbes' */

  // getters
  int capacity() { return nSlot; }
  int size() { return nElem; }
  double load_factor() { return load; }
  int getSearchProbes() { return probesSearch; }

  private:
  /* declare your data */
  double load;     // track the load factor of table
  int    nSlot;    // # slots i.e. max # elements can hold 
  int    nElem;    // current # elements in table
  int    arr[];
  int    probesSearch;
};

#endif
```

HashTable.cc

```
#include "HashTable.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class HashTable
{
  public:


  HashTable()
  {
    load = 0;
    nSlot = 300;//nSlot is changable in order to optimize
    nElem = 0;
    arr = new int[nSlot];
    probesSearch=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<nSlot;i++)
    {
      arr[i] = NULL;
    }
  }
```

Some of the things I've tried are adding any and all includes I could think of, changing the last line shown in insert_test.cc to "HashTable h = new HashTable();"(where I got a different error), adding namespace std to the header. I feel like it should be a quick fix but at the same time I can't find the solution anywhere. Plz send help

Comment: Your makefile doesn’t show you compiling `HashTable.cc`, only `insert_test.cc`.

Comment: Your program violates One Definition Rule; it defines `class HashTable` differently in two translation units. Consult your favorite C++ textbook for a correct syntax for an out-of-class definition of a member function.

Comment: This `arr = new int[nSlot];` doesn't have a `delete[]` counterpart. Before using `new` - **THINK** because it's likely to bite you.

Comment: You have to link the object for HashTable while linking.

Comment: `HashTable.cc` should not have `class Hashtable { ...` at all. You already have that in the header. You can't redefine the class in the implementation file. To implement class members in the implementation file you need to use for example the constructor: `HashTable::HashTable() {// Implementation of the constructor goes here}` Your `c++` book should explain this.

Comment: Here is a reference: [https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/member-functions-cpp.php](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/member-functions-cpp.php)